# PHP - Program redirects to itself but this does not work when launched by CRON

Tags: php, html, cron

I have a program that calls itself iteratively.

```
redirect($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

function redirect($url,$seconds=0) { 
$html="<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='$seconds; URL=$url'></head></html>";
echo $html;
exit();
}
```

If I start it from the URL it works great, but if I launch it with CRON it does not work.

Is there another way to make a program call itself that will work with CRON?

Comment: Think about it for a second. A cron has no endpoint to which it can redirect.

Comment: cron accesses the script just as you would on the command line. If you use cron to access a URL, it just does a GET request (such as you would with curl or wget), so HTML has no effect.

Comment: The CLI doesn't render the output like a browser does, so HTML and JavaScript have no effect. `cron` already runs the script repeatedly, why do you need to use `meta refresh`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another way to make a program call itself that will work with CRON?

Yes, there is. You can use exec in your code instead of the redirect:

```
exec("php script.php");
```

or

```
exec("/usr/bin/php script.php");
```